# Check if checkbox is checked using function prop

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbk" class="cbk" name="cbk">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('#cbk:checked').prop('checked'))
{
    alert('Checked');
}
else
{
    alert('Uncheck');
}
</script>
```

I try but there is no alert, i also tried `$('#cbk:checked').attr("checked")?1:0;` but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

```
 $('#checkbox').is(':checked');
```

The above code returns true if the checkbox is checked or false if not.

so your code will be

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="cbk" class="cbk" name="cbk">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('#cbk').is(':checked'))
{
    alert('Checked');
}
else
{
    alert('Uncheck');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try this:Another way is $('#cbk').attr('checked'), which is equivalent to $('#' + id).is(":checked") but easier to remember.

Comment: i use this $('#cbk').attr('checked') but it alway return true

Comment: let me see what u did.

Comment: Take care of duplicated ids, maybe it's your problem. This should work: `$('#cbk').prop('checked')`. This works if `#cbk` is **unique** in the whole page.

Comment: Yes, it should work and its alternatives are also works. I m using it and works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
if(document.getElementById('cbk').prop("checked") == true)
{
}
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById('cbk').checked)
{
}
```